# Advances on migration from ClearCase to SVN

Tags: svn, configuration, migration, clearcase

I am a ClearCase user and abour to plan for ClearCase - SVN migration. The project is fairly large, there are branches and labels. Before starting a plan, I want to learn experiences about this migration.

- Will this migration cause some data to be lost?
- Is migrating all the history is efficient or has some problems?
- Are there any efficient and experienced tools to migrate ClearCase to SVN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ClearCase is file-based (each checkin creates a new version for *one* file), and its labels are also file-based (you set a label on a file or files, not always *all* the files).

As opposed to Subversion, which is repository-based, where each commit creates a new revision for the *all* repo content.

You can try one free tool like [Polarion SVN Importer](https://www.polarion.com/products/svn/svn_importer) ([quite old 2010](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cc2svn/downloads)), to try and import the full history, but I usually:

- only import the last relevant labels,
- leave the ClearCase VOb in read-only mode for archive.